# Green Screen Image Processing Chroma Key Live Video

Tags: c++, xcode, image-processing, chromakey

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [avassetwriter with greenscreen or chromakey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756554/avassetwriter-with-greenscreen-or-chromakey)

I am trying to make an IOS application that is able to take the live video feed from the camera and implement a green screen/chroma key effect. I have seen some methods, but they always seem to spark some error on my computer and it shows it only works with IOS 5 or up and I want one that is able to work with lower ones as well. Just to summarize, I have no clue how to do it and I want something that is able to take a live video feed from the camera and then add onto it with an image that has a green screen background. Thank you in advance!